# How to display record count in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, controller

this is my controller query:

```
$orderStatistics = OrderHeader::orderBy('order_status')
    ->select(DB::raw('order_status,count(*) as count'))
    ->groupBy('order_status')
    ->get();
```

and this returns a response as this:

```
"data": [
{
  "order_status": "APR",
  "count": 2
},
{
  "order_status": "CNCL",
  "count": 4
},
{
  "order_status": "NTE",
  "count": 3
},
{
  "order_status": "PND",
  "count": 2
},
{
  "order_status": "SHP",
  "count": 1
}
```

]

how can I return the relevant order_status and it's count for example as this:

```
APR : 2
```

Comment: where do you want to display ? do you want print in view page ?

Comment: no I want to return $orderStatistics as above example

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way to format data like `APR : 2` this ..

```
$orderStatistics = OrderHeader::orderBy('order_status')
    ->select(DB::raw('order_status,count(*) as count'))
    ->groupBy('order_status')
    ->get();

   $orderStatistics =   $orderStatistics->map(function($item){
                   return [
                    $item->order_status => $item->count,
                   ];
               });
```

Comment: am getting this error: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Comment: after execute the query you iterate the `$orderStatistics`  variable ..

Comment: sorry, can you provide me an example?

Comment: otherwise  you can try with `mapWithKeys()` function...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221802/discussion-between-abdullah-al-noor-and-user13080158).

Answer (score 0):

You can use transform function on your collection:

```php
$result = $result->transform(function($re){
        return //your changes on an object ($re)
})
```

If you want make an array for JsonResponse:

```php
$data=[];
foreach($results as $re){
$data[$re->order_status]=$re->count;
}

return response()->json($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $numb = 0;
  $newOrderStatus=[];
    foreach($orderStatistics as $orderStatistic){
     array_push($newOrderStatus, $orderStatistic->data[$numb]->order_status.':'.$orderStatistic->data[$numb]->count;
     $numb++
    }
    echo $newOrderStatus[0];// your example but you just return $newOrderStatus
    return response()->json($newOrderStatus);
```

This is what i would think of fast if you want to echo it to a view as array object you just parse return response()->json($newOrderStatus) But as you receive it javascript will see it as a string so you have to parseJson(receiveddata);